# how to add bootstrap's feedback/errors in grails?

Tags: grails

what's the best way to add an error icon/make the field red  after form submit ?
the following way doesn't seem to me so practical :

```
<div class="form-group <g:hasErrors bean="${user}" field="username">has-feedback has-error</g:hasErrors>">
        <label for="username" ><g:message code="page.signup.label.username"/> : </label>
        <input type="username" class="form-control" id="username">
        <g:hasErrors bean="${user}" field="username">
             <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o form-control-feedback"></i>
        </g:hasErrors>
</div>
```

and how to make the error icon disappear once the input's text is changed? Would it be better if I submit the form using AJAX ?
Thank you !

> I know how to do it (show errors), but i'm looking for best practices (doesn't matter if it's only with grails, or with jquery and angular or any other framework)

Answer (score 1):

Well that's really easy with the help of spring error class `org.springframework.validation.Errors` as it has many utility method one of which is `getFieldError`.

Suppose you have domain:

```
class Address{
String address
String city

static constraints = {
city nullable false
address nullable false
}
}
```

Suppose we have domain object address like below:

```
  Address address  = new Address(address:"test address")
```

in gsp page, we could put an if condition like below:

```
<g:if test="${address.errors.getFieldError('city') != null}">
//your html code. 
</g:if>
```

In html code, you could put an inline message and also, to change text box outline to RED, you could declare a css class which could be added to field if error is there.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! :)